# If a permutation $\sigma$ has $\sigma (k)=k$ and $ts$=$st$, then $t(k)=k$ also

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\sigma \in S_n$ a cycle of length $n-1$ such that $\sigma(a_k)=a_k$. Prove that if $t \in S_n$ satisfies $ts = st$ then also $t(a_k)=a_k$.

So I supposed $\sigma = (a_1 ... a_{k-1} a_{k+1} ... a_n)(a_k)$,

We have: $(*) : (a_1 ... a_{k-1} a_{k+1} ... a_n)(a_k)t = t(a_1 ... a_{k-1} a_{k+1} ... a_n)(a_k)$. I assumed by contradiction that $t(a_k) \neq a_k$, then $t(a_k) = a_i$ for some $a_i\neq a_k$.

On the left of $(*)$ we have that $a_k \rightarrow \text{(goes to)} a_i \rightarrow a_{i+1}$ and on the right we have $a_{k}\rightarrow a_k\rightarrow a_i$. Is that enough of a contradiction?

Comment: If $a_i = a_n$ then $a_{i+1}$ is simply $a_1 \neq a_k$, no?

Comment: Where does $s$ come from? Do you mean $s = \sigma$? And what is $a_k$? Is it some element $a_k \in \{1, \dotsc, n\}$?

Comment: I'd say that is enough. As you say, if $\tau(\sigma(a_k)) = \sigma(\tau(a_k)) \implies \tau(a_k) = \sigma(\tau(a_k))$. As $\sigma$ is a cycle of length $n-1$, this is only the case for $\tau(a_k) = a_k$.